# How to change background image of a ImageButton in android

Tags: android

I am facing a situation in which-
1.First I have to set the background image of a ImageButton to a default image.
2.Now at runtime based on some condition I have to change the background image of that ImageButton to some other image.

I have tried this but it doesn't work and the background image remains to default image and 
doesn't change.

```
 btn.invalidateDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));
                btn.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.infonewred));
```

How can I achieve this goal.

Comment: could you post your xml, where you have set the default image?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.infonewred)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you set the "default" Background directly in your XML-Layout-File via `android:background`.
If you have to change the Background in Runtime just use `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename);`

Answer (score 1):

since you haven't provided xml, i am guessing you are providing src to imageButton.. so to change the source of the image , what you are doing is changing the image background which will not be visible since it is the source which will be visible to you.. so to change source..

do this.

```
btn.setImageDrawable()
```

rather than..

```
btn.setBackgroundDrawable()
```

Comment: well I am not declaring ImageButton in xml file rather I am creating directly via code and then adding it to the layout. Please look at the exact code and suggest as it is not working yet..ImageButton btn=new ImageButton(MainActivity.this);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));
layout.addView(btn);
if(condition)
{
btn.invalidateDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));     
  btn.setImageDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.infonewred));
}

Comment: you should post the code , as how you are setting the default image.., post in the question, so that everyone will be able to see it.

Comment: you don't need this line ..  btn.invalidateDrawable((Drawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info)); and also.. use setBackgroundDrawable as how you were doing earlier.. ,,, last but not least, did you check if you are hitting the condition?, i mean check if your condition is true first..

Answer (score 1):

I know that's old but i got the solution as i'm also was searching for that, the correct answer is to use `setImageResource` , so the code will be like that:

```
btn.invalidateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.info));
btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.infonewred);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the method setImageResource

Ex:

```
if(someCondition()){
   btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.info);
} else {
   btn.setImageResource(R.drawable.infonewred);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try following code to change at runtime and for default view set background property in layout xml:

```
if(yourCondition)
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.infonewred);
```

Answer (score 0):

in activity file you can write
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sliderr);

OR

in your xml layout file you can add one extra line to you button xml code 
android:src="@drawable/sliderr"